# convert xml which has 'children' into dictionary

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, elementtree

I have a xml file which has childrens and I want to convert it into a dict.

```
<people>
 <type>
  <name>lo_123</name>
  <country>AUS</country>
  <note>
     <name>joe</name>
     <gender>m</gender>
     <age>26</age>
     <spouse>
         <name>lisa</name>
         <gender>f</gender>
     </spouse>     
  </note>
 </type>
</people>
```

This is my code to convert it

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

xml='xmltest.xml'

crif_tree = ET.parse(xml)
crif_root = crif_tree.getroot()
data = []

for one in crif_root.findall('.//type'):
    reg={e.tag: e.text for e in list(note1)}
    data.append(reg)
for two in crif_root.findall('.//type/note'):
    reg={e.tag: e.text for e in list(note1)}
    data.append(reg)
for three in crif_root.findall('.//type/note/spouse'):
    reg={e.tag: e.text for e in list(note1)}
    data.append(reg)

print(data)
```

Here is the output of `data`

```
[{'name': 'lo_123', 'country': 'AUS', 'note': '\n     '}, {'name': 'joe', 'gender': 'm', 'age': '26', 'spouse': '\n         '}, {'name': 'lisa', 'gender': 'f'}]
```

My desired output would be

```
[{'name': 'lo_123', 'country': 'AUS', 'note': '\n     ', 'name': 'joe', 'gender': 'm', 'age': '26', 'spouse': '\n         ', 'name': 'lisa', 'gender': 'f'}]
```

Comment: so you have `name` multiple times as a key , that's not advisable as you may run into issues when calling the key, it may return only the last value of `name`

Comment: "xmltodict" is a very useful module for this.